# The records that fire the after trigger are read-only

Tags: apex, trigger

I know that "The records that fire the after trigger are read-only." as given in apex developer guide. But why the records are read only.

Comment: Short answer - to prevent an infinite recursion loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations to what you can do to the record that is triggering and after trigger, so you won't get in an endless loop.
Because from a logical perspective the trigger would be triggered, insert something, trigger again based on its own action, insert something, trigger again...

To make it harder to get in an endless loop Salesforce there are those constraints.